# Unable to Import Pandas in Python2.7

Tags: python, pandas, macos

I have two versions of Python installed in my mac: Python2.7 and python 3.7. 
When I try to install Pandas using Pip,

```
pip install pandas
```

It shows,

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2019.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.12.0)
```

Upon Importing pandas, it prompts an error: No Module Found.

```
Raghus-MacBook-Pro:~ Home$ python Python 2.7.16 (default, Aug  6 2019, 11:00:03)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I have also tried ,

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

But it doesn't solve my issue. Pandas gets imported with python3. But i want pandas to be imported with python. Is it the Problem with the Directory? Help me out.

Comment: make sure you have activated virtual ENV where you installed panda

Answer (score 2):

Your default py version is python2.7. 
Whereas, you're installing pandas on py3. 
Try

```sh
pip2 install pandas
```

to install on py2.7

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to run python 3 instead of python 2, it might be a good idea to use an conda environment to create a project-specific python 3 environment in which you install pandas. Then you can use the package from there.

so you install anaconda and type this

```
conda create -n pandaenv
conda activate pandaenv
conda install pip
pip install pandas
python
>>> import pandas
```

you might also replace line 3 and 4 by

```
conda install pandas
```

Comment: Why is conda better than venv? I've never heard of conda :|

Comment: I guess you can do the same with venv or pipenv. I never used them, but the benefit of conda is that it manages packages for you based on the dependencies. So if I type e.g. "conda install tensorflow" it suggests a whole list of packages for me to install.